# Combobox binding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am trying to bind combobox in WPF. Here is my xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbRptType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ReportTypes}" SelectedValuePath="Type" DisplayMemberPath="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="198">

        </ComboBox>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<ReportType> ReportTypes = new ObservableCollection<ReportType>()
        {
            new ReportType() { Name = "Store", Type = REPORT_TYPE.STORE },
            new ReportType() { Name = "Customer", Type = REPORT_TYPE.CUSTOMERS }
        };
```

and within the constructor I have set:

```
DataContext = this;
```

But my items are not showing up. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Make your ReportTypes a property by adding {get; set;} and create new instance in your contructor

Comment: You can't bind to a **field**.

Comment: Are Name & Type fields or properties of ReportType? They need to be properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note in the below code, not using _reportTypes and instead using ReportTypes would result in a eternal loop as it would to update itself for eternity.**

```
private ObservableCollection<ReportType> _reportTypes
public ObservableCollection<ReportType> ReportTypes
  {
     get{return _reportTypes;}
     set
     {
        _reportTypes = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.ReportTypes);
     }
  }
```

you forgot to set the getter and the setter of the ObservableCollection, getters and setters are VERY important when using binding.

the setter takes the "value" you pass it and sets the variable's value.

the getter waits to be called and when called it returns the variable value to the item that called it.

**Combobox property**

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding ReportTypes,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

setting the mode and the UpdateTrigger is also very important

via the mode you can set the way the combobox interacts with the binding.

with the UpdateSourceTrigger you can tell the combobox to wait for the item it is binded to to be updated and then it asks the getter for the updated data

Comment: Observable collection already implements INotifyPropertyChanged, you don't have to do it again

Comment: @NawedNabiZada You do, if you dont NotifyPropertyChanged, it just doesn't update....atleast to my experience

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, try this solution and you'll be surprised ;) But otherwise you are correct: if you don't set value to a new instance there is no need to rise notification, e.g. auto-property with getter only will do perfectly, including adding/deleting items.

Comment: @chimchillas That is because you are doing it wrong. Instantiate it once, and rest of the time use .Clear() and .Add() method, then you will see magic happen

Comment: @NawedNabiZada believe me, I use .Add() and .Clear()

It just does not work if you dont NotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 1):

If your combobox items are only going to be a fixed list then you don't need an observable collection to achieve binding. If you're going to modify `ReportTypes` and want those changes reflected in the combobox then you need to use the observable collection.

```
public enum REPORT_TYPE
{
    STORE,
    CUSTOMERS
}

public class ReportType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public REPORT_TYPE Type { get; set; }
}

public List<ReportType> ReportTypes { get; set; } = new List<ReportType>()
{
    new ReportType() { Name = "Store", Type = REPORT_TYPE.STORE },
    new ReportType() { Name = "Customer", Type = REPORT_TYPE.CUSTOMERS }
};
```